# Enviar variable c# por post a otra página

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar el evío de una variable nacida en c# a través del método POST para trabajarla en una página externa en php.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Test
{
class Program
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 string url = "localhost/test.php";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.QueryString.Add("param1", "a");
    wc.QueryString.Add("param2", "b");
    wc.QueryString.Add("param3", "c");

    var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);

    var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
}
}
```

Estoy recibiendo este error:

> CS0246 El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'WebClient' no se
>   encontró. Falta una directiva using o referencia de ensamblador?

Busqué pero no encontré cómo avanzar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega la directiva `using System.Net;`

WebClient es una clase que pertenece a este NameSpace, para mas informacion: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Te esta faltando el

```
using System.Net;
```

Para poder usar la clase `WebClient`

Si quieres enviar por post no defines el `QueryString` sino que usas el `NameValueCollection`

Algo como ser

```
var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("param1", "a");
parameters.Add("param2", "b");
parameters.Add("param3", "c");

var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameters);
```

Analiza los ejemplos de la documentacion oficial

[WebClient.UploadValues Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues?view=netframework-4.5)